# Cannot run a FQL example. Encountering unexpected problems before the query

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I want to ask a newbie question. I'm just starting to creating a website that will use FQL to get user data for analysis and i have encountered a problem before i even start. I'm trying to run this code that i found in facebook developer site for example:

```
$app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$app_secret = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
$my_url = 'POST_AUTH_URL';

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

// auth user
if(empty($code)) {
  $dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' 
  $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) ;
  echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}

// get user access_token
$token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
. $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) 
. '&client_secret=' . $app_secret 
. '&code=' . $code;

// response is of the format "access_token=AAAC..."
$access_token = substr(file_get_contents($token_url), 13);

// run fql query
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
. 'fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()'
. '&access_token=' . $access_token;
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
```

I changed my app_id and my app_secret and at my_url i added my canvas url (but i'm not sure if that is correct).

I never get to run the query and get the results because i encounter the problem here:

```
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
```

The problem is:

**Notice: Undefined index: code in C:...\index.php on line 77**

Should i change the "code" part? and into what?

Comment: If it is unclear, the value for `$my_url` should be the url where you then try to get the code, for example, back to that script. Do you even get redirected by the Javascript to the auth dialog? Make sure that you are using an account with tester/developer/admin role for the app if your app is still in Sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a [Notice (not a Warning, or Error)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).

You could put this at the top of your code to suppress the message.

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```